# Sort array based on key => value pair

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I am trying to sort an array based on the `key=>value` but I can't get this done. Here is the code I am working out:

```
$arr = [
    '183034' => 9,
    '183033' => 6,
    '183032' => 3,
    '183002' => null,
    '182973' => null,
    '182971' => null,
    '182969' => null,
    '182999' => null,
    '182997' => null,
    '182995' => null,
    '182962' => null,
    '182948' => null
];

$arrTemp = [];

foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
    $arrTemp[$key] = $value;
}

array_multisort($arrTemp, SORT_NUMERIC, $arr);

var_export($arrTemp);
```

The output is:

```
#php test.php
array (
  0 => NULL,
  1 => NULL,
  2 => NULL,
  3 => NULL,
  4 => NULL,
  5 => NULL,
  6 => NULL,
  7 => NULL,
  8 => NULL,
  9 => 3,
  10 => 6,
  11 => 9,
)
```

But I expect something like:

```
array (
    '183002' => null,
    '182973' => null,
    '182971' => null,
    '183032' => 3,
    '182969' => null,
    '182999' => null,
    '183033' => 6,
    '182997' => null,
    '182995' => null,
    '183034' => 9,
    '182962' => null,
    '182948' => null    
);
```

Where value define the position where the item should be moved on. In other words let's take an example by words: `'183032' => 3` this item is holding position 3 on the result array so what I should do is keep the same array order but move that item to position 3 as you may notice on the output array. Same for `'183033' => 6` where this one holds position 6 so I reorder the whole array to move this to position 6 and so on. Can any give me some help?

**UPDATE**

What about if I change original `$arr` into this:

```
$arr = [
    '183034' => ['sort_position' => 9],
    '183033' => ['sort_position' => 5],
    '183032' => ['sort_position' => 3],
    '183002' => [],
    '182973' => [],
    '182971' => [],
    '182969' => [],
    '182999' => [],
    '182997' => [],
    '182995' => [],
    '182962' => [],
    '182948' => []
];
```

Is almost the same but this is how the array should look (just an example) and arrays with `[]` should have other keys inside I just don't write them here because the relevant is `sort_position`.

Comment: Try [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php), it's pretty great :)

Comment: maybe `SORT_DESC | SORT_NUMERIC` ??

Comment: Can you please explain the output, you want.

Comment: @Andrew no, isn't working it leaves the array intact and I loose the key values all the time

Comment: @KishanKumar not sure what are you asking me but is only sort array by its value on keys. As you can notice `'183034' => 9,` was moved to position `9` on the output array, that's all, sort them by the value.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php or http://php.net/manual/en/function.krsort.php

Comment: @DamienPirsy the desired output key is not in order of `ASC`

Comment: Have you tried a simple `krsort()`

Comment: What about krsort()?

Comment: maybe  uksort($arr, "strnatcmp");

Comment: 1/ extract null values from the array into another array, then sort it by key 2/ insert each not-null value from the original array into new array by position (given by value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr = [
    '183034' => ['sort_position' => 9],
    '183033' => ['sort_position' => 5],
    '183032' => ['sort_position' => 3],
    '183002' => [],
    '182973' => [],
    '182971' => [],
    '182969' => [],
    '182999' => [],
    '182997' => [],
    '182995' => [],
    '182962' => [],
    '182948' => []
];
$count = count($arr);
$tmp=[];
//sort by key descending
krsort($arr);
foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
    //if element has a sort position
    if(isset($val['sort_position'])){
        //save it in tmp, indexed by sort position
        $tmp[$val['sort_position']]=$val;
        //and remove it from original array
        unset($arr[$key]);
    }
}
//Note $arr now only contains elements without sort position

$out=[];
//build new array of same length as original
for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++){
    //if there is an element in temp with this sort position, use it
    //else grab the next one from the non sort position elements
    $out[] = isset($tmp[$i])? $tmp[$i] : array_shift($arr);
}

var_dump($out);
```

EDIT just realized i missed the importance of the array keys. Maybe you dont actually need the keys after all, but for completeness here is a modified solution that preserves the keys as well:

```
$count = count($arr);
$has_sortorder=[];
$no_sortorder=[];
krsort($arr);
foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
    if(isset($val['sort_position'])){
        $has_sortorder[$val['sort_position']]=[$key, $val];
    }else{
        $no_sortorder[]=[$key, $val];
    }
}


$out=[];
for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++){
    if(isset($has_sortorder[$i])){
        $out[$has_sortorder[$i][0]] = $has_sortorder[$i][1];
    }else{
        $element = array_shift($no_sortorder);
        $out[$element[0]] = $element[1];
    }
}

var_dump($out);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is closer that I was looking for, this help and with comments, simply nice

Answer (score 1):

Imho this is not a sorting problem, as you have multiple element impossible to sort (null values should stay all at the same place, at the beginning or at the end of the array).

Your problem is related to the positioning of some elements in their right place.
I think you should solve it iterating over the array.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f72cc2ef661f805a9f5a8a491c2cf5455ed31c60

```
$arr = array(
    '183034' => 9,
    '183033' => 6,
    '183032' => 3,
    '183002' => null,
    '182973' => null,
    '182971' => null,
    '182969' => null,
    '182999' => null,
    '182997' => 10,
    '182995' => null,
    '182962' => null,
    '182948' => null
);

// sort by value and maintaiming key value association
// separate null values from numeric values
// null values a start of array 
// numeric values at end of array
asort($arr, SORT_NATURAL);



// this is a temporary array used to store every single row from $arr
// as a array value
// the keys of this array start with 0 and are positional
$arrTemp = [];

   
foreach ( $arr as $key => $value ) {
  if ( is_numeric($value) ) {
    // insert into $arrTemp the numeric value at the correct position
    // because we arsorted $arr before, the splice does not push
    // numeric values behind
    array_splice($arrTemp, $value, 0, array(array($key => $value)));
  } else {
    // these are the null values, they fill up the start of $arrTemp
    $arrTemp[] = array($key => $value);
  }
}

$arrOut = array();


// get the array of arrays back into a hash array
foreach ( $arrTemp as $value ) {
  list($key, $val) = each($value);
  $arrOut[$key] = $val;
}

print_r($arrOut);
```

---

#### edit

after the change in specs from OP it would be this solution

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f72cc2ef661f805a9f5a8a491c2cf5455ed31c60

```
$arr = array(
    '183034' => array('sort_position' => 9),
    '183033' => array('sort_position' => 5),
    '183032' => array('sort_position' => 3),
    '183002' => array(),
    '182973' => array(),
    '182971' => array(),
    '182969' => array(),
    '182999' => array(),
    '182997' => array(),
    '182995' => array(),
    '182962' => array(),
    '182948' => array(),
);

$arrTemp = [];

uasort($arr, 'compare_function');


foreach ( $arr as $key => $value ) {
  if ( !empty($value) && is_numeric($value['sort_position']) ) {
    array_splice($arrTemp, $value['sort_position'], 0, array(array($key => $value)));
  } else {
    $arrTemp[] = array($key => $value);
  }
}

$arrOut = array();

foreach ( $arrTemp as $value ) {
  list($key, $val) = each($value);
  $arrOut[$key] = $val;
}

print_r($arrOut);


function compare_function($a, $b) {
    if ( isset($a['sort_position']) && !isset($b['sort_position']) ) {
        return 1;
    }
    if ( isset($b['sort_position']) && !isset($a['sort_position']) ) {
        return -1;
    }
    if ( isset($a['sort_position']) && isset($b['sort_position']) ) {
        if ( (int) $a['sort_position'] == (int) $b['sort_position']  ) {
            return 0;
        }
        return (int) $a['sort_position'] < (int) $b['sort_position'] ? -1 : 1;
    }

}
```

Comment: Excellent, that's exactly what I am looking for, thanks now let me learn from your solution

Comment: Can you update your code based on my update? Your code still working with first approach and I will drop that soon

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2a70db53b59578bdda20c043109be038b2f0f47f